# sql - filtering results of a select statement - build a user suggestion query

Tags: mysql, sql, social-networking

I have a social network based sql structue including a table 'follows', where a column has the userid of the follower and the userid of the person who gets followed. Pretty simple.

Now I want to build a user suggestion tool. I need a query that gets me the users that the people i'm following are following. And of course it also needs to sort out the people I'm already following and it should count the amount of my following people that are following a specific person, so I can sort the suggestions.

```
SELECT
  users.userid,
  users.username,
  COUNT(me.from_userid)

FROM follows AS he

INNER JOIN users
   ON users.userid = he.to_userid

LEFT  JOIN follows AS me
   ON me.from_userid = 33
  AND me.to_userid = he.from_userid

WHERE me.to_userid != he.to_userid
GROUP BY users.userid
```

I already built a query, but somehow it just gives me like all the users and just the number of one's user's followers in general.

I tried to explain the wanted query in an example, so it's easier to understand. (userid = 1 is me)

[image: unable to show this picture]

**Would be so great If anybody can help me out with that!**

Answer (score 0):

Please see the solution below

Data

```
CREATE TABLE follows
(from_user_id INT,
 to_user_id   INT);

INSERT INTO follows VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO follows VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO follows VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO follows VALUES (2, 4);

CREATE TABLE users
(user_id INT, 
 user_name VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'TEST1');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'TEST2');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3, 'TEST3');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (4, 'TEST4');
```

Solution

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, COUNT(*)
  FROM follows his JOIN 
       (SELECT DISTINCT he.to_user_id
            FROM follows me JOIN follows he 
                              ON (me.to_user_id = he.from_user_id)
          WHERE me.from_user_id = 1
            AND he.to_user_id NOT IN 
                       (SELECT me.to_user_id
                          FROM follows me 
                         WHERE me.from_user_id = 1)) my
        ON his.to_user_id = my.to_user_id 
        JOIN users u
        ON (his.to_user_id = u.user_id)
 GROUP BY u.user_id, u.user_name;
```

Output

```
user_id user_name   COUNT(*)
3       TEST3       1
```

Explanation

- Subquery (my) - Finds all the people who follows my followers. Also exclude the ones who are my followers already.
- Main query - Finds the list of people who follow the person returned from the subquery and does a group by to get the number of people following him/ her.

Hope this helps. Please let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: The selection of the users works pretty well. But the 'count' column still only shows all followers of the user. I need it to show the number of the followers which i'm following too. So I can sort it for relevance

Comment: That's what I thought the query is doing. Can you give me a sample dataset and expected output please?

Comment: Imagine there a more users following User3. So maybe 10 followers. The counter should stay at 1 then anyway, because only **1 of my friends** (=the people i'm following) is following User3. You understand?